# Adam is thinner than Barbara. Dalton is less thin than Celia. Adam is less thin than Celia

Tags: theory

Option:

**A)** Adam is thinner than Dalton.

**B)** Bárbara is thinner than Adam.

**C)** Célia is thinner than Bárbara.

**D)** Célia is less thin than Dalton.

**E)** Bárbara is thinner than Dalton.

The right response is **C**, but not function in the following code:

```
adam='a'
barbara='b'
dalton='c'
celia='d'

adam = dalton
barbara > adam
barbara > celia
celia < dalton
barbara > dalton
adam > celia
```

Because when I check the option **B**, **D** and **E** is True and **C** is False.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score -1):

When I replace the string for integer the code work properly.

```
adam = 2
barbara = 3
dalton = 2
celia = 1

adam = dalton
barbara > adam
barbara > celia
celia < dalton
barbara > dalton
adam > celia
```

Now the **C** is True and others options is False.